# Calculate new coordinates from old coordinates and x and y

Tags: java, math, coordinates

I have the following setup of items in real life:

[image: My setup]

The radar is static, which means it always has the same position. The `A`-item can move and its position can be whatever. From the radar I can read the `x` and `y` coordinates of `A` in relation to the radar. I have written the following classes to describe the position of each item:

```
public class Position {
    public enum Direction {
        EAST, WEST, NORTH, SOUTH
    };

    public final Direction latitudeDirection, longitudeDirection;
    public final float latitude, longitude, altitude;

    public Position(Direction latitudeDirection, Direction longitudeDirection,
            float latitude, float longitude, float altitude) {
        this.latitudeDirection = latitudeDirection;
        this.longitudeDirection = longitudeDirection;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
        this.altitude = altitude;
    }

    public Position(float radarX, float radarY) {
        // TODO: Implement the question here
        this.altitude = Config.RADAR_POSITION.altitude;
    }

}

class Config {
    // Position of the radar
    public static final Position RADAR_POSITION = new Position(
            Position.Direction.NORTH, // Latitude direction
            Position.Direction.EAST, // Longitude direction
            55.0f, // Latitude
            13.0f, // Longitude
            60.0f); // Altitude

    // Facing direction of the radar in degrees. 0° is north, advancing
    // clockwise.
    public static final float RADAR_FACING_DIRECTION = 10.0f;
}
```

Now given the geographic coordinates of the radar, the `x` and `y` coordinates of `A` relative to the radar and the facing direction of the radar relative to the North, how can I calculate the absolute geographic coordinates of `A`?

The curvature of the earth is not an issue since the maximum value of `x` and/or `y` cannot be more than a couple hundred meters.

Comment: Your problem amounts to rotating an image 10 degrees. There are plenty of literature on the matter. Once rotated you add the coordinates of your origin (the radar).

Comment: But that would be wrong. Geographic coordinates are degrees from the core of the earth. My coordinates in reference to the radar are just meters. I cannot add those two together.

Comment: Given that (x,y) be the current coordinate `A` . And if you know the angel (theta) to which radar is rotated with respect to the earth , then you can easily find the new cordinates(xnew,ynew) as : `xnew = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta);
ynew = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);`

Comment: Ok I thought your question was about the rotation of the reference frame. For the last issue, Universal Traverse Mercator has the easting and northing in meters. Converting to UTM, adding the values and converting back to geographic should do the trick. Alternatively, it is not difficult to find how many meters a second of longitude is at a relative latitude (seconds of latitude have a fixed length at all the longitudes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be possible to do it this way:  Convert the `x` and `y` coordinates to polar coordinates `r` and `theta`, (with the radar as the origin).  Subtract the radar's rotation, and convert back to cartesian coordinates.  Then you just have to convert to latitude and longitude and add the coordinates of the radar.

```
double r = Math.hypot(radarX, radarY);
double theta = Math.atan2(radarY, radarX);
theta -= Math.toRadians(Config.RADAR_FACING_DIRECTION);
float x = (float) r * Math.cos(theta);
float y = (float) r * Math.sin(theta);
longitude = metersToLongitude(Config.RADAR_POSITION, y) + Config.RADAR_POSITION.longitude;
latitude = metersToLatitude(Config.RADAR_POSITION, x) + Config.RADAR_POSITION.latitude;
```

I found formulae for the length of a degree of latitude and longitude on Wikipedia.  A degree of latitude is the same everywhere but longitude gets smaller near the poles.

```
static float metersToLatitude(Position near, float meters) {
    return meters / 110.6*1000;
}

static float metersToLongitude(Position near, float meters) {
    float lat = Math.toRadians(near.latitude);
    return meters /
        (111132.954 - 559.822 * Math.cos(2*lat) + 1.175 * Math.cos(4*lat));
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

If you want to express your coordinates in positive degrees east/west/north/south you'll also have to check if they're negative and invert them and the direction in that case.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer inspired me. You can find the code I used in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

As an example, you can use trigonometric functions to create triangles to find coordinates of A:

[image: Example of using trigonometric functions]

In this case, Ax = (y)(cos 10) - (x)(cos 80), and you could work out Ay similarly.

This way, you are never stuck in degrees, you are simply working in meters.

The robust solution is Vishal's comment in the OP, which was posted whilst I was drawing and scanning:

```
xnew = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta); 
ynew = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);
```

Answer (score 2):

In general, you can use the following steps:

1. transform your radar position (lat, lon, height) into metric earth centered earth fixed xyz-system (ECEF)
2. You can then use/combine any rotation and translation arguments/matrices, which describe radar rotation and object position, in this metric system
3. back transform newly acquired xzy coordinates to lat/lon/h

There are many ressources for such transformations, check this, for instance: http://www.gmat.unsw.edu.au/snap/gps/clynch_pdfs/coordcvt.pdf

You can also introduce a scene coordinate system, if needed (ENU). Here is a fairly good overview describing the relation of UTM, ECEF, ENU and geodotic coordinates(Lat/lon/h):
http://www.dirsig.org/docs/new/coordinates.html

If you need sample code for ECEF to/from Geodetic conversion, have a look at the matlab code, http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/map/ref/ecef2geodetic.html,
or use a library like GDAL (http://www.gdal.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Does this help for conversion?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_system#From_geodetic_to_ECEF ?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it. The code is attached below. Since Samuel Edwin Ward's answer is the one that inspired me, I will accept his answer.

```
public Position(float radarX, float radarY) {

    // Convert A's position to distance and bearing in relation to the North 
    double objDistance = (Math.hypot(radarX, radarY) / 6367500 /* Mean earth radius */);
    double objBearing = (Math.atan2(radarY, radarX) + Math.toRadians(Config.RADAR_BEARING));

    // Convert the Radar's geographic coordinates to radians
    double latitudeRadar = Math.toRadians(Config.RADAR_POSITION.latitude);
    double longitudeRadar = Math.toRadians(Config.RADAR_POSITION.longitude);

    // Calculate A's geographic coordinates in radians
    double latitudeObject = Math.asin(Math.sin(latitudeRadar)*Math.cos(objDistance) + 
            Math.cos(latitudeRadar)*Math.sin(objDistance)*Math.cos(objBearing));
    double longitudeObject = longitudeRadar + Math.atan2(Math.sin(objBearing)*Math.sin(objDistance)*Math.cos(latitudeRadar), 
            Math.cos(objDistance)-Math.sin(latitudeRadar)*Math.sin(latitudeObject));

    // Normalize to -180 ... +180 degrees
    longitudeObject = (longitudeObject+3*Math.PI) % (2*Math.PI) - Math.PI;  

    // Set the A's coordinates in degrees
    this.latitude = (float) Math.toDegrees(latitudeObject);
    this.longitude = (float) Math.toDegrees(longitudeObject);

    // Set the rest of the arguments
    this.latitudeDirection = Config.RADAR_POSITION.latitudeDirection;
    this.longitudeDirection = Config.RADAR_POSITION.longitudeDirection;
    this.altitude = Config.RADAR_POSITION.altitude;
}
```

Comment: Getting rid of the meters as soon as possible is really bright.  Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: Does this seem to be accurate enough though, with the Earth not being a sphere?

Comment: If you see the longitude calculation takes into account the latitude. Therefore it works for an ellipsoid.

Answer (score 0):

You rotate all coordinates in the local system of the radar -10° and are then able to just add the radar's x/y coordinates to the A object coordinates.

Comment: As I said above, that would be wrong. Geographic coordinates are degrees from the core of the earth. My coordinates in reference to the radar are in meters. I cannot add those two together.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the text, let me think again *g*